# typo3: some concerns on extension file ext_emconf.php

Tags: typo3

In extension file:ext_emconf.php

```
<?php
$EM_CONF[$_EXTKEY] = array(
    'title' => 'AJAX Search',
    'description' => '',
    'category' => 'plugin',
...
```

According to the document here: http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_api/4.3.2/view/2/1/

I know it is for `Definition of extension properties`, but I still have questions on:

1. for `$EM_CONF`, I guess it is for extension management configuration, but in which file, I can check how does EM use it?
2. for  `$_EXTKEY`, I think it is the extension key, i.e. for above extension, ext key is `ajax_search`, so in which file, `ajax_search` assign to `$_EXTKEY`? such as: `$_EXTKEY = ajax_search`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What do you want to do? The values are normally read via `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['extConf'][$_EXTKEY]` after initialization. You can browse them using the backend module `Admin Tools => Configuration`, then select the correct array with the selectbox at the top.
2. Have a look in you `typo3conf/temp_CACHED_*_ext_localconf.php` file. The `$_EXTKEY` is set there. The extension list is iterated through and all config files are put together and cached this way. The `$_EXTKEY` variables are set during this process.